# How to know the place Scala implicit definition come from?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I developed a class that takes an `implicit engineProvider: ClientSSLEngineProvider` as a constructor parameter. When I instantiate the class, I don't have any implicit definition of such type anywhere within my source file, however the code compiles without any errors. When I use debugger, I can see that this parameter is initialized with some value. It looks like this implicit is defined somewhere else (in one of the imports).

How can I locate the exact place where it is defined? I'm using IDEA for development, if it matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe just use `-Xprint:typer` to see what was used:

```
$ scala -Xprint:typer

scala> Future(1)

     private[this] val res0: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.Future.apply[Int](1)(scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global);
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are using sbt add this line into your `build.sbt` build file.

```
scalacOptions in ThisBuild += "-Xlog-implicits"
```

I'd also suggest you to take a look at the companion object of `ClientSSLEngineProvider` (it's one of default sources for implicits)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, with -Xlog-implicits I can only see a lot of stuff about `materializing requested scala.reflect.type.ClassTag[...]`. And nothing about implicit parameters. EDITED: ah, of course, ClassTag IS an implicit parameter. But still nothing about the one I am interested in.